# AutoComplete No longer working in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, autocomplete

In Salesforce classic the browser would auto complete certain fields. However, after changing to lightning this is no longer occurring. We are using Google Chrome but are experiencing this issue with Firefox as well. Has anyone had any luck getting this fixed or have a solution? See pictures below that show lighting without the autocomplete and classic where it is showing autocomplete.

Thank you for any help!

[image: NO Auto Fill Text]

[image: Auto Fill Working in Classic]

Comment: i think this one auto populate things related to browser settings, if your using Google check ctrl+H ---> clear browser data --> advanced--- auto fill form data check box